# Struts 2 JQuery multicolored bar chart

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I am using a Struts 2 jQuery bar chart, the code for which is

```
<sjc:chart
                        id="chartInteger"
                        xaxisColor="#666"
                        xaxisPosition="bottom"
                        xaxisTick="[[0,''],[1,''],[2,'Fours Weeks'],[3,''],[4,'Three Weeks'],[5,''],[6,'Two Weeks'],[7,''],[8,'One Week'],[9,''],[10,''],[11,''],[12,'']]"
                        xaxisTickDecimals="20"
                        yaxisPosition="left"
                        cssStyle="width: 340px; height: 220px;"
                        onClickTopics="chartClick"
                        onHoverTopics="chartHover"
                        xaxisMode="time"
                        legendShow="#ccc"
                        legendPosition="sw"
                        xaxisMax="12"
                        xaxisMin="0"
                        yaxisMin="0"

                    >
                        <sjc:chartData 
                            list="IntegerFromMap"
                            color="#ff2b00"
                            bars="{ show: true}"
                        />
```

Here I am getting four bars with single color, but my requirement is multicolored bars, for example each bar starts with red then green then yellow, Is this possible here and if possible how, I searched through the net but wasn't able to find a solution for it, any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You mean the bars are gradients? Or each bar has one colour?

Comment: each bar has mutiple colors, vertically divided

Comment: Ah, you'll need something custom if done with JS.  Try to avoid using UI tag libraries simply use JS/jQuery. One issue with the JS solution is testing across different browswers, perhaps an image would be better? There are a number of drawing/charting/reporting frameworks for Java which might be equally appropriate. Supporting only newer browsers, the html 5 canvas would probably be easiest.